# Why is there so much whitespace between the two divs?

Tags: html, css

[Picture of the white space between "header" and "content"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNVt.png)

I just got back into web work and cannot figure this out! Theres a big gap between the header div and the content div that isn't present with the sidebar div and the code isn't too different for each one so thats why it confuses me. I don't know where the whitespace is coming from.

I took some stuff out of my code that wasn't relevant but let me know if theres something that isn't there.

```
<!-- Page Wrap -->
<div class="pagewrap">
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
<img src="images/Logo.jpg" width="530" height="180" alt=""/>
</div>
<!-- Header end -->

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="sidebartitle">
<center style="color: #FFFFFF">Specials</center>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<center>
<div class="page-popper">

          </div>
<table width="187" height="196" border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="buttonImageWrapper">
<img src="images/M-2.jpg" alt=""/>
</div></td>
        <td>
        <a href="/appointment.html">Request an Appointment</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="buttonImageWrapper">
        <img src="images/M-2.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div></td>
        <td><a href="/pdf/Salon-Menu.pdf">Salon Menu</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="buttonImageWrapper"><img src="images/M-2.jpg" alt=""/></div></td>
        <td><a href="/pdf/Spa-Menu.pdf">Spa Menu</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="buttonImageWrapper"><img src="images/M-2.jpg" alt=""/></div></td>
        <td><a href="/bridal-services.html">Bridal Services</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="facebookImageWrapper"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" width="48" height="48"></div></td>
        <td><a href="">Like us on Facebook</a></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  </center>
</div>
<!-- Sidebar end -->

<!-- Content -->
<div class="contenttitle">
<center style="color: #FFFFFF">Welcome</center>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <!-- Picture Slider -->
    <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="top"><div id="p7IRM_1" class="p7IRM01">
                <div id="p7IRMow_1" class="p7IRMowrapper">
                  <div id="p7IRMw_1" class="p7IRMwrapper">
                    <div id="p7IRMdv_1" class="p7IRMdv"><a class="p7IRMlink" id="p7IRMlk_1" title=""><img class="p7IRMimage" src="../images/new/slide-show1/000.jpg" alt="000" name="p7IRMim_1" width="350" height="233" id="p7IRMim_1" /></a></div>
                    <div id="p7IRMdsw_1" class="p7IRMdesc_wrapper">
                      <div class="p7IRMdesc_close"><a id="p7IRMdsclose_1" href="javascript:;" title="Hide Description"><em>Hide</em></a></div>
                      <div id="p7IRMds_1" class="p7IRMdesc">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="p7IRMdsopw_1" class="p7IRMdesc_open_wrapper">
                      <div id="p7IRMdsop_1" class="p7IRMdesc_open"><a id="p7IRMdsopen_1" href="javascript:;" title="Show Description"><em>Show</em></a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <ul id="p7IRMlist_1" class="p7IRMlist">
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/000.jpg">000</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/001.jpg">001</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/002.jpg">002</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/003.jpg">003</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/004.jpg">004</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/005.jpg">005</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/006.jpg">006</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../images/new/slide-show1/007.jpg">007</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!--[if IE 5.000]>
<style>.p7IRMdesc_wrapper {position:static !important;visibility:visible !important;}.p7IRMdesc_open_wrapper, .p7IRMdesc_close {display: none;}.p7IRMpaginator {position: static !important;height: 3em;}.p7IRMpaginator li, .p7IRMpaginator a {float: left !important;}.p7IRMpaginator a {float: left !important;overflow: visible !important;}</style>
<![endif]-->
                <!--[if lte IE 6]>
<style>.p7IRMpaginator a {width: auto !important;}</style>
<![endif]-->
                <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>.p7IRMpaginator li {display: inline !important;margin-right: 3px !important;}.p7IRMpaginator {zoom: 1;}</style>
<![endif]-->
                <script type="text/javascript">P7_opIRM('p7IRM_1',1,1,1,3000,4000,1,0,1,0,1500,0,0);</script>
              </div></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    <!-- Picture Slider end -->
    <p><strong></strong><br />
         <br />
<br />
        </p>
        <p><a href="salon-services.html">Salon Services</a> | <a href="spa-services.html">Spa Services</a> | <a href="spa-packages.html">Spa Packages</a> | <a href="bridal-services.html">Bridal Services</a> | <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a> | <a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Content end -->
```

and the css

```
.pagewrap {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
background-color: black;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header img {
width: 55%;
}

.sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 16px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
                padding: 10px;  

border: #000000 solid 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
}

.sidebartitle {
border: #000000 solid 2px;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-top-right-radius: 2em;
        padding: 10px;  

height: auto;
width: 200px;

background-color: #68316B;
}

.content {
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 16px;
            float: right;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 10px;      
border: #000000 solid 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
}

.contenttitle {
border: #000000 solid 2px;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-top-right-radius: 2em;
            float: right;
                    padding: 10px;  

font-size: 16px;
width: 600px;
height: auto;

background-color: #68316B;
}
```

Comment: What's with all the tables....have you been away for 20 years? Also `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: In Chrome Right Click on the "content" Inspect Element and check the styles tab to check which styles are being applied and check the Computed tab" to see the box model too.

Comment: I'm not the greatest at web development but I'm really decent so thats why so many tables, it looks good though I think. You're right I forgot to take away center. I'll make a JSFiddle now.

Comment: If we're trying to recreate a 90's website, there aren't nearly enough `<blink>` and `<marquee>` tags.

Comment: you have IE 5 comments in there... we all burned IE 6 in a fire last year and pissed on the ashes. I don't think you could actually find a working copy of IE 5 if you tried.

Comment: Hahaha, its an old website and I don't notice that and blow right past. They're websites my dad worked on that I help him with. Funny thing is most of his websites do like they are from the 90's (thats when he started his company) and I've modernized them. I'll have to take that down when I get the chance but its not hurting anything! Also, what should I do instead of tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that `.sidebartitle` isn't floating, so `.contenttitle` won't float right of it, but stays below it. If you float `.sidebartitle`, however, `.sidebar` will be right of `.sidebartitle`, so just put a wrapper DIV around sidebartitle AND sidebar and make *that* `float:left;`.

See the result here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqdNzy

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!!